# Worst case complexity for this python code

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the worst case time complexity of the following:

```
def fun(n):
    count=0
    i=n
    while i>0:
        for j in range(0,i):
            count+=1
        i/=2
    return count
```

Comment: Just curious, is this a homework question. Did you try doing some work on it first.

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3? Division works differently for i/2 if i is integer

Comment: its Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 0):

Worst case time complexity if n is really big integer.

O(log(n)*n) (**Guessing**).

Here's how I came to my conclusion.

```
while i>0:
        ...
        i/=2
```

This will run log(n) times because it's getting halved every time it runs.

```
for j in range(0,i):
```

This will run n times first, n/2 times the 2nd time, and so on. So, total running time for this line is n + n/2 + n/4 .... 1 = (2n-1)

```
count+=1
```

This is a cheap operation so is O(1).

Thus making total running time of this function **O(log(n)) * O(2n-1)**, if n is an integer. Simplifying becomes **O(log(n)*(n))**.

Comment: `2n-1` is the total number of operations performed by the inner loop, not the nubmer of operations performed on every iteration of the outer loop. Therefore, `2n-1` and `log(n)` should be added, not multiplied; and the total time complexity will be `O(n)`. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708311/two-loops-but-thetan